# How is the viscosity solution is $C^2$ away from $z=0$. The domain $B_R \cup {z \neq 0}$ already contains the point $z=0$.

Tags: functional-analysis, partial-differential-equations, regularity-theory-of-pdes, viscosity-solutions

In Caffarelli and Silvestre's extension problem paper [link of paper](https://arxiv.org/pdf/math/0608640.pdf) [Lemma 4.2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3xdBh.png), in Lemma 4.2, it is given that the viscosity solution is $C^2$ away from $z=0$. How do we have a classical solution on $B_R \cup \{z \neq 0\}$? As $z=0$ is already contained in the Ball $B_R$. Please help me out with this doubt.

Comment: Silvestre is also an author of the paper

Comment: It’s not super clear what your question is. Are you asking why a viscosity solution to (1.8) in the paper is a classical solution of $\Delta_x u +\vert z\vert^a u_{zz}=0$ in $B_R\setminus \{ z=0\}$?

Comment: Yeah Sorry. I have added the author name. I am asking the same as mentioned in your comment.

Answer (score 0):

Looking to the Lemma, I guess that $ \{z \ne 0\}$ is short for $\{ (x,z) \in \mathbb R^2 \mid z \ne 0\}$.